# calculated formule help

Tags: calculated-column

I have a field Title with value like below

Title=3.10-gotomeeting

I want a calculate formule to remove ("-")and (".") so that the output should be only a  number i.e "310".

Can any one help me on this ..I have achieved this by using 2 calculated formules like below. but i want it in one.

order is the name of calucltaed column.

```
=LEFT([Title],SEARCH("-",[Title])-1)
```

porder is the name of another calculated column

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(".",order,1))
    ,order
    ,REPLACE(order,SEARCH(".",order,1),1,"")
   )+0
```

Answer (score 0):

After Digging in to it i finally made it .

```
=LEFT(REPLACE([Title],SEARCH(".",[Title]),1,"")
,SEARCH("-",REPLACE([Title],SEARCH(".",[Title]),1,"")
)-1)+0
```

Explanation:

REPLACE([Title],SEARCH(".",[Title]),1,"")

This replaces (in the value of the "Title" field), starting at the position of the first occurance of the "." character, for a length of 1 (replacing 1 character only), with nothing (empty quotes).  This gets rid of the first dot.

To get the rest of "-"

```
LEFT([Title],SEARCH("-",[Title])-1)
```

We need to pass the above replace formule in place of title

So, what it comes down to is that in order to replace all occurances of a given character within a string, we need to know how many times it appears then nest the replacement logic that many times.

Hopefully this clears things up some.